# How do I make the contents of a Scala List implicitly available?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a `List` of items (in this case Spray Marshallers) which I want to make implicitly available in the current context. Just to clarify: I don't want the `List` itself to be implicitly available, but each element of the list. Does anyone have trick to do this? Or is this actually not possible since the exact implicits have to be available at compile time?

Comment: Do you have any example code of where/how you would use it?

Comment: For every type only one instance can be selected by implicit search. If multiple instances are available and implicit search can't choose, you'll get `error: ambiguous implicit values`. Every element in a `List[T]` has type `T`. So how would that work out?

Comment: Some more context: I was trying to create a directive as part of a library that would allow users to have multiple versions of their HTTP API. This directive would bring the correct marshallers into scope. This solution however combines compile time and runtime logic w.r.t. implicits. I've now chosen a different path: a custom `complete` directive that replaces the original one and takes an implicit list of marshallers as an argument. This directive picks the correct marshaller and creates the response. Works like a charm! Thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, if I understood correctly, you need to have all your specific marshallers available in a context, hence you need to provide each of them implicitly.

You should put them into an object and define them as implicit values.

```
object Protocol {
  implicit val marshaller1: ...
  implicit val marshaller2: ...
}
```

Then, by importing the `Protocol` object, you would have all your marshallers implicitly available.

And to answer to your question, yes, implicits are resolved at compile time. Hence, whenever you need to use a specific marshaller, the implicit resolution algorithm will look for a `value` of the specific marshaller type. This is why you cannot get it from a list, let's say, and you shouldn't want this either way.

Comment: This works only if the various marshallers are declared as different types. See comment above. If you disagree, please provide functioning code.

Comment: Your answer made me realize that I was on the wrong track with my solution... Thanks for making me come to my senses ;)

Comment: @Jan-Pieter I am really glad.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve this with shapeless:

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Selector

case class A()
case class B()
case class C()

val list : A :: B :: C :: HNil = A() :: B() :: C() :: HNil

def screamIfAccessible[T](implicit selector: Selector[A :: B :: C :: HNil ,T]) = {
  selector(list) // Actually picks the T type element 
                 // from the HList to work with
  println("YAY!")
}

screamIfAccessible[A]
screamIfAccessible[B]
```

[Shapeless - Generic programming with scala](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

Any method in your code that needs access to an element of type A from the list(or in this case HList) needs to have the `Selector` implicit argument